# Randomly distributed objects into containers

Tags: algorithms, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, packing-problem

I need to generate a set o random numbers that will be used to distribute some objects in containers.

All containers can store up to 5 objects except for one, that can store up to 14 objects.

I have 25 containers and 70 objects.

What I'm doing now is generating 25 random numbers between 0 and 14. Then I sum all of them to normalize the initial set, dividing each number by the sum.

So now I have a set of numbers that represents the proportion of objects in each container.

To get the number of objects for each container I multiply the proportion by 70, but here I get a problem. The proportions are all floating point numbers, and I can only store an entire object on each container.

If I round the numbers some numbers are rounded up, and some down. Then when I sum all objects I can get anything between more or less 65~75. But I need to distribute exactly the 70 objects.

Does anyone have an ideia on how to fix it?

Or any other ideas on how to solve this?

I don't necessarily need to follow this approach, I can use any method to transform the initial random set into the distribution. My requirements are only that:

- the initial set of data must be random integer numbers (any quantity or range)
- given two identical initial sets, the distribution of the objects into the containers must be the same

Comment: How precise are you as to what "random" means? For instance:  you could start by tossing objects into the bins uniformly at random (choose a random integer from $1$ to $25$).  Then, when a bin is filled, choose a random integer from $1$ to $24$ (relabeling the non-filled bins) and so on.  Is that ok?

Comment: If you wanted to favor the big bin, you could choose an integer uniformly at random  from $1$ to $5\times 24 +14=134$ and say that  $1-5$ goes in bin 1, $6-10$ in bin $2$ up to $121-134$ go to the big bin.  If a bin is filled go to the next random number and so on.

Comment: @lulu This way I don't have an initial set of random numbers. The existance of this initial set is a requirement. How the set is generated doesn't matter here, just assume that I have something that can generate random integers numbers in any amount and range. This will be used on a genetic algorithm for optimization, so this is the reason that I need to have and initial set of randmon numbers (fully defined) to then use them to transform in a distribution. But none of the containers should be favored.

Comment: You can generate the random number list initially...no problem.  If you do it the first way, you can entirely pre-generate the list (you'll need several, to account for the rapidly filling bins).  If you do it the second way you only need one list but there's a theoretical possibility that it won't be long enough.  If your list is a thousand terms  long I don't think is much a practical impediment but that's up to you.

Comment: @lulu The problem of the first way is that it's filling up the bins, I need random distributions, which could or couldn't fulfill a given bin.

Comment: Well, then I think you need to declare what you mean by random.  It isn't clear.  My method is quite random.  You can favor the big bin or not, it's still random.  But perhaps you have a strict definition of random you are trying to satisfy.

Comment: To be clear:  my methods don't intentionally fill bins.  I just throw balls randomly into urns.  When I throw one into an urn that's filled, I try again.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, I misread your first option. You're absolutely right, this could be a solution. I'll play with it to see how well it performs and I'll tell you